# How to Mock services in JAR

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have one class

```
class ServiceA{
public Service2 service2Obj;
  public ServiceA(){

           }
    public ServiceA(Service2 service2Obj){
     this.service2Obj = service2Obj;

     }
public Response updateMetadata(String templateId,
        InputStream metadataStream)
        throws InternalServerError,ServiceException,
        NotFoundException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, String> metadataMap = null;
    String status = null;
             metadataMap = mapper.readValue(metadataStream, Map.class);
             String i = service2Obj.updateMetadataService(templateId, metadataMap);

    }
    return Response.ok().entity(i).build();
}
}
```

My test case is as follows

```
 @Test
  public  void test(){
     Service2 mockService = Mockito.mock(Service2.class);
     ServiceA ServiceAObj= new ServiceA(mockService);

    Mockito.when(mockService.updateMetadataService("1",  readJsonString()))
            .thenReturn(readJsonString());
    // run method under test
    Response response = ServiceAObj.updateMetadata("1",new ByteArrayInputStream(
            "{\"title\":\"TEST\"}".getBytes());

    Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());

    // Parse json and get value from json string
    String totalItems = (String) convertMapToJson(
            (response.readEntity(Object.class))).get("title");

    Mockito.verify(mockDocStoreImpl).updateMetadataService("1",readJsonString()); // getting here error wanted but not invoked

}



public static JSONObject readJsonString(String json)
            throws DocGenServiceException {
         String json = "{\"title\":\"TEST\"}";

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
        return obj;
    }
```

Service2 class is in my JAR file could this be the reason of failure of Test ???
Should I test to verify the method in JAR, i.e. Service2 Class???
Can I use this
`verify(mockService).method2("1");` // i am using this but getting error saying wanted but not invoked

Comment: Are you injecting your `mockService` into `ServiceAObj`?

Comment: Mockito can't mock static methods. Only instance methods.

Comment: its not a static method @JBNizet

Comment: yes m passing mockServiceObj into ServiceAObj constructor @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: @user3969239 Not in the code you posted, though.

Comment: Then show your real code. ServiceA has no reference to any Service2 instance, and the method call is Service2obj.method2(id), with a capital S, which means to any Java developer that you're calling a method on a class, and not on an object. We can't help you with your code if you're not showing it.

Comment: Please check now I have edited the code

Comment: And it still doesn't compile. Write code that compiles, in your IDE, and respect the Java naming conventions. Make sure it's correctly indented. Then run it, then and only then, if it doesn't work like you think it should do, post the actual code you wrote and compiled.

Comment: check edited i have posted real one @JBNizet

Comment: check edited i have posted real one @RobbyCornelissen

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `JSONObject` that you try to match on in your `when` statement is not the same (object identity) as the one that will be passed to your method, and the one you use in your `verify` statement. This is due to the fact that `readJsonString()` will return a new object every time.

Initialize your `JSONOBject` once and reuse it for both statements wrapped in a [`Mockito.eq()` matcher](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html#eq%28T%29).

```
JSONObject json = readJsonString();
Mockito.when(mockService.updateMetadataService(
    Mockito.eq("1"), Mockito.eq(json))).thenReturn(json);

// ...

Mockito.verify(mockDocStoreImpl).updateMetadataService(
    Mockito.eq("1"), Mockito.eq(json));
```